# SQL: How do do where statement Where X OR Y is equal to &SUBSTITUTION VALUE

Tags: mysql, sql

x or y = &substitution_Value. doing where x=&subvalue or y=&subvalue requires a repeat in the input which i want to avoid

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator: `WHERE &subvalue IN(x, y)`.